# AdSense head script element is dropping performance

Tags: html, adsense

I'm trying to add ads to my web app and I used adsense and it's telling me to paste this script to the head of the html

```
<script async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js?client=ca-pub-secret-client-number"
     crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Without this script and running lighthouse I get a performance score of 99 and after using it it drops down to 70-75

Should I use Partytown or is there a way around

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Partytown.

I recently added Partytown to our site. In the research I did for it, I didn't really find anything that offers [offloading the script to a web worker](https://partytown.builder.io/how-does-partytown-work#service-worker) like Partytown does. It's fairly simple to implement and provides a significant boost to performance.

It's important to note that [it is still in beta](https://www.builder.io/blog/partytown-is-now-in-beta), so there may be bugs. But in my experience, working with it has been pretty smooth.

Comment: Yeah I tried it before while the adsense checks were still running and my app got rejected should I add Partytown after my app is approved?

Comment: Maybe. I've never used AdSense before, but saw that they had some eligibility requirements. I'd imagine as long as your meeting those, you should be fine.

Comment: This may be against adsense rules?